# How to run the AudioKit unit tests?

Tags: audiokit

I've made local changes with Xcode to AudioKit, and have tried running the tests from Xcode, but the unit test process fails to start:

```
The bundle “AudioKitTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
```

Can somebody please point me to documentation that describes how to run the test for my changes?

Thanks in advance, Pete